# My python code give this type error ''IndentationError: expected an indented block".give any solution

Tags: python-3.x

```
#!/bin/python

for i in range(1000):   #153
    pre = i     #pre=153
    a =str (i)  #a='153'
    sum=0
    for j in a:
        k = int (j) #k=1
        q = k*k*k
        summ = summ+q
    if (pre = summ):
        print("Armstorng ",pre)
    else
        print("not Armstorng ",pre)
```

Comment: Which line of code produces the error?

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Why did you rollback @krock edit ?

Comment: if(pre = summ) this line show error @jkdev

Comment: Thank you !! this is my first post and i'm newbie on SO .this post is not looking well, i think this post need some edit so can you provide me any tips or online manual. @lvan Gabriele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (pre = summ):
```

That should be a double equals sign because it's a comparison between two values, not a variable assignment.

```
if (pre == summ):
```

Also, a couple of (potential) spelling errors: "Armstorng" and "summ". (Unless you intend "sum"/"summ" to be different variables.)

Comment: You're welcome! Please click the checkmark next to my answer if it is the right solution.